# MobClix error for iPhone -503?

Tags: iphone, mobclix

I have integrated MobClix to my app, the test adds are working correctly before entering my MobClix application ID, after giving actual MobClix ID i am getting below error.
( I have checked my MobClix applicationID, and also i have enabled only 320*50 add i used the same in code they are correct) Dont know why i am getting this error.

> Error Domain=com.mobclix.ads Code=-503 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.mobclix.ads error -503.)"

Comment: I didn't use MobClix yet. But I know it is supported by AdWhirl. Did you try this lib?

Comment: But in MobClix site... they recommended not to use via AdWhirl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following [the steps here](http://support.mobclix.com/entries/483771-how-to-diagnose-common-errors-by-error-code). If that still doesn't work, submit a support ticket and we can take a look into your account.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mobclix Team. It worked for me the problem was I didn't sign in any Ad network after signing in it worked like a charm :)

Comment: Great! Glad it's up and running now. Let us know if you have any other questions/problems.